# Learning to read French for fluent speakers

Tags: orthographe, ressources, apprentissage

What are some good resources to learn how to read French for those who already have a solid command on speaking it?

<sup>This is somewhat the converse of my question: "[Drilling tools for active mastery?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/42717/6587)"</sup>

Comment: I thought you said you were not a fluent speaker. The obvious answer is to read newspapers, magazines and books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never been in that situation, but here's what I would try:

- Watch french speaking (or dubbed) videos/films/series with french subtitles activated. This way, when you hear a sentence, you'll get used to seeing it written.
- Read books using a writing style close to spoken french, allowing you to make easy connection with the oral. (Litterature would be somewhat challenging coming from a spoken-only french background). News or magazine articles with a casual writing style could do the job too (avoid *Le monde* or other "serious" papers)

Comment: +1 for your 2nd suggestion.